# Lost how this string permutation code works?

Tags: java, recursion

I can't grasp how this string permutation codes is working.  I understand how it moved the chars around from str to prefix, but when I trace how it's working I'm totally confused how it's going to the next permutation.

For instance the word "cubs"

### it's output is String prefix + " " + String str

cubs

c ubs

cu bs

cub s

cubs    <---------- I understand how it gets here

cu bs   <---------- I don't understand how it starts back up here?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        permutation("cubs");        
    }

    public static void permutation(String str) {
        permutation("", str);
    }

    public static void permutation(String prefix, String str) {
        int n = str.length();
        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println(prefix);         
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                System.out.println(prefix + " " + str);

                permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n));               
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try to have a look at how recursion works. That is what is probably what you are missing out. Maybe this can give you some clues https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Order_of_execution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if interpreted your problem correctly. I think you're wondering why you have this duplicate, right? And I furthermore assume that you don't just want a working solution, because you probably want to solve the problem yourself, right?

In your for-loop you print something that will in some cases be printed again when recursively calling `permutation`.

The fact that you print in the loop makes this quite likely. If you only print outside the loop (`if (some condition) print(this); else print that`) you can much easier avoid duplications.

Actually you might not want to print anything in the `else` part.

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me see if I can explain it for you. The best way to think of recursion is to consider it as a hierarchy - each nested call is a level down in the hierarchy.

So when you call perm with "","cubs" it will call the following in turn:

```
c,ubs
u,cbs
b,cus
s,cub
```

If you consider the first call "c","ubs" it will call:

```
cu,bs
cb,us
cs,ub
```

And the first of those "cu","bs" will call with args:

```
cub,s
cus,b
```

And the first of thos "cub","s" will call with args:

```
cubs,
```

Now the second argument string has length 0 so there is no deeper recursion.

Putting the entire hierarchy together for c,ubs it looks like

```
,cubs
    c,ubs
        cu,bs
            cub,s
                cubs,
            cus,b
                cusb,
        cb,us
            cbu,s
                cbus,
            cbs,u
                cbsu,
        cs,ub
            cus,b
                cusb,
            cub,s
                cubs,
    u,cbs
        ...
```

Hopefully you can see how that will work through every combination in turn.

You specifically asked how it started back at "cu bs". The reason for that is that you are printing `prefix + " " + str` on every iteration so it'll print that same text 3 times before each recursive call. If you want to trace the recursion it probably makes more sense to print once at the start of the call. The following in the body of the function will probably give output that make more sense:

```
System.out.println(prefix + " " + str);
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, str.length())); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll try the change to see if I can understand this more.

Comment: So after the prefix is cubs and str is " ", I just still don't get how it becomes cus,b unless it back peddles.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this, after str become 0, it moves back to a previous hierarchy?

Comment: @YachtRocker yes that's correct. That's how recursion works. At str length 0 it pops out of the fuction